# net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(null) doesn't throw any exception?

Tags: java, json

I have been trying to run following code block. Found out this behaviour.

```
net.sf.json.JSONObject json = net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(null);
if(json!=null) {
        System.out.println(json);
}
```

It doesn't throw any exception. Output is "null"

When I add size check.,

```
net.sf.json.JSONObject json = net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(null);
if(json!=null && json.size()>0) {
         System.out.println(json);
}
```

It throws exception like this.,

> Exception in thread "main" net.sf.json.JSONException: null object
> at net.sf.json.JSONObject.verifyIsNull(JSONObject.java:2856)
> at net.sf.json.JSONObject.size(JSONObject.java:2516)

I had long search on this but no luck. can someone explain this behaviour else redirect to the apt site.
Also help me in how to execute this if block with proper null & empty check.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try upcasting to generic [Message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Message) type, that should make it easier.